# how do I trim git output to get rid of ctl-m and square brackets

Tags: git

Just noticed that git started messing some of my scripts.
For example if I type **"git branch -a > br.txt"**, the br.txt file looks like the following (below) when I try to edit it, and also if I tried to pipe the command's output for further processing it fails since there are no branches by those names:

```
  user/branch1^[[m
  user/branch2^[[m
  user/branch3^[[m
* ^[[32mmaster^[[m
  ^[[31mremotes/origin/HEAD^[[m -> origin/master
  ^[[31mremotes/origin/master^[[m
```

How do I get rid of these extra characters, (not by trimming the lines after the fact), but I am assuming there must be some configuration that changed. I am on a MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, git version 2.29.1

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: those are control characters that change the color or style of the text in your CLI

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+redirect+strange+characters

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
git branch -a --no-color
```

Comment: tried that but that didn't do it, you're right it should, but ... and as @andersryanc mentioned above I'm aware that they are the color controls.

Comment: This answer by @Marco did the trick.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git